# Validating name field using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Actually I am new to jquery as well as web designing

Now I need some piece of code which will invoke after blur event on a text box.

I need jquery code for validating a name field in the html form.

Comment: @ZoltanToth i mean check weather that is a name or not...for example if i enter 3sam ,it should show error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add a latest version of jQuery....
Here is a sample for validating for not null.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input#fname').on('blur', function() {
            if( $(this).val() == ''  || $(this).val() == "null") {
                // Your code to handle error
            } else {
                            return true;
                    }
        })
    });
```

Comment: this will fail if the user enters `32#78@*!` or `3sam` as a name

Answer (score 5):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/gZNkt/

```
$("#fname").on("blur", function() {
    if ( $(this).val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$') ) {
        alert( "Valid name" );
    } else {
        alert("That's not a name");
    }
});
```

It will check your name to be 3-16 characters long and contain only letters, so `sam` will validate, but `3sam` - won't

Comment: 2-16 characters are better, there are names from asian countries like "Li" which are shorter then 3 characters

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to validate your text box after focus out or blur in jQuery.

You can use below code for the same purpose :-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#fnam").blur(function() {

      if($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == undefined || $(this).val() == "")
      {
         alert("field is empty");
      }

   });

// if you want this validation on focus lost
 $("#fnam").focusout(function() {

  if($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == undefined || $(this).val() == "")
  {
     alert("field is empty");
  }

   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#reg").bind("keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.charCode!=0) {
                var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
                var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
                if (!regex.test(key)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

you disable press key and allow only charecters ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with the  [jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: actually iam new to jquery...can you help me pls

Comment: First of all you gotta download the Plugin and add it to your html code, you can download the necessary files in http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery-validation-1.9.0.zip .
Then when you create your form, for example the input where the name it's gonna go you create it like this:<br/>
`<input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />`
And then in you javascript you just do:<br/>
`$('#yourForm').validate();`

Comment: In the very first link i provided there is a whole lot of other examples you can experiment with